Typescript generic formatter type determination
I'm creating overloaded useFetch hook, which has optional error formatter.
The error formatter can return any type, therefor the type is generic.
For some reason, typescript does not assign generic type ErrType from from parameter function formatError.
Who knows why, and how to do it?
type UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, ErrType> = {
  data: ResponseType | null,
  error: ErrType | null,
  loading: boolean
};

function useFecth<ResponseType>(url: string): UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, string>;
function useFecth<
  ResponseType,
  ErrType,
>(url: string, formatError: (x: any) => ErrType): UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, ErrType>;

function useFecth<ResponseType>(url: string, formatError?: (x: any) => unknown) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return {
    data,
    error,
    loading,
  };
}


const { data: numArr, error: numberErr } = useFecth<number[]>('https://url1', (x: any): number => 7);
const { data: stringVal, error: boolErr } = useFecth<string>('https://url2', (x: any): boolean => false);
const { data: stringArr, error: stringErr } = useFecth<string[]>('https://url2');

I also tried with simplified example, and it works! And I don't get it why the useFetch does not.
// Function return type used as a generic, which works
function fnWrapper(): string;
function fnWrapper<T>(callback: () => T): T;
function fnWrapper(cb?: () => unknown) {
  return  cb !== undefined ? cb() : 'default value';
}

const a = fnWrapper(() => 7);
const b = fnWrapper(() => 'String val');
const c = fnWrapper();

Code here:

One limitation of TS is that when inferring generics, if one of the generics is provided, TS stops inferring of all the generics.  Meaning the moment we pass the response generic argument to useFetch TS is not going to try and infer the 2nd generic argument for ErrorType.
So a workaround is providing the error return type  when passing in the error function.
type UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, ErrType> = {
  data: ResponseType | null;
  error: ErrType;
  loading: boolean;
};

declare function useFetch<ResponseType>(
  url: string,
): UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, null>;
declare function useFetch<ResponseType, ErrorResponse>(
  url: string,
  formatError: (args: any) => ErrorResponse,
): UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, ErrorResponse>;
declare function useFetch<ResponseType, ErrorResponse>(
  url: string,
  formatError?: (args: any) => ErrorResponse,
): UseFetchReturnType<ResponseType, ErrorResponse>;

const { data: numArr, error: numberErr } = useFetch<
  number[],
  number
>("https://url1", (x: any) => 7);
const { data: stringVal, error: boolErr } = useFetch<string, boolean>(
  "https://url2",
  (x: any): boolean => false,
);
const { data: stringArr, error: stringErr } =
  useFetch<string[]>("https://url2");


